# How to get latest message for conversation between users? (Chat system)

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a private messages system.

I want to get the latest message as per conversation time. Now it is showing the messages in chronological order but I want it in reverse-chronological manner, latest message on top and so on.

### Table

```
SELECT `messages`.`id`,
    `messages`.`sender`,
    `messages`.`receiver`,
    `messages`.`message`,
    `messages`.`datetime`,
    `messages`.`classifield_id`
FROM `augl`.`messages`;
```

### Function

```
public function getMessageList()
{
    $current_user = $this->accounts->getUserId();

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM(
                                SELECT id, LEAST(receiver) as receiver, LEAST(sender) AS sender, message, datetime, classifield_id 
        FROM messages
        WHERE sender='$current_user' OR receiver = '$current_user' 
        Group By (if(sender > receiver,  sender, receiver))
               , (if(sender > receiver,  receiver, sender))
        ) 
            as id");

    $result =  $query->result();

    //var_dump($result); die;

    foreach ($result as $messages )
    {
        $return[$messages->id] = $messages;

        if ($messages->receiver === $current_user)
        {
            $return[$messages->id]->userr = $this->accounts->getUsername($messages->sender);
            $return[$messages->id]->userid = $messages->sender;
            //$return[$messages->id]->message = $messages->message;

        }
        else
        {
            $return[$messages->id]->userr = $this->accounts->getUsername($messages->receiver);
            $return[$messages->id]->userid = $messages->receiver;
            //$return[$messages->id]->message = $messages->message;
        }


    }

    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you change "LEAST" to "GREATEST" that may fix it.

Answer (score 0):

See the tutorial in the MySQL Manual. you want [GROUPWISE MAXIMUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) obviously MIN and not MAX for your needs.